# Failed.........error: bind message supplies 3 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1

Tags: postgis, postgresql, node-js

I am using node to capture gps data from my devices after every 30 seconds, i want to store the data into a table but when executing the query statement it throws an error

`Failed.........error: bind message supplies 3 parameters, but prepared statement "" requires 1`, i am using prepared statements. My geometry field is a `PointField`, database `Postgresql` with `postgis`. any one having a clue.

My query code:
`

```
client.query("INSERT INTO gpsdevices_coordinate (gpsdevice, geometry) VALUES ($1, ST_GeomFromText(\'POINT($2 $3)\', 4326))", [this.getUID(), data.longitude, data.latitude], (err, res) => {
console.log("Failed........." + err);
 //Do something where done
        })
```

`